# map replace between two dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, replace

I need to replace values of a column in a dataframe with values from another dataframe based on **if** condition.

Here is sample example of my question:

Let's say,I have two data frames like below.

first - DF1

```
19-SOURCE   19-AMOUNT       19-SOURCE_PRK
P_ER SH M       456             ER SH M
P_ER SH NE      823             ER SH NE
P_Rvr           346             Rvr
P_Rvr A-T       175             Rvr A-T
P_Rvr R         446             Rvr R
P_U ER Act      642             U ER Act
```

second - DF2

```
PRK Source      Fid seq Num
P_U ER Act      4
P_Rvr R         8
P_Rvr A-T       9
P_Rvr           7
P_ER SH NE      13
P_ER SH M       3
```

Here is my complete code

```
    import pandas as pd
    
data1 = [['P_ER SH M',  456 ,'ER SH M'],
    ['P_ER SH NE'   ,823    ,'ER SH NE'],
    ['P_Rvr'    ,346 ,  'Rvr'],
    ['P_Rvr A-T'    ,175    ,'Rvr A-T'],
    ['P_Rvr R', '446',  'Rvr R'],
    ['P_U ER Act'   ,'642'  ,'U ER Act']]
    
    
data2=[['P_U ER Act',   '4'],
    ['P_Rvr R'  ,'8'],
    ['P_Rvr A-T'    ,'9'],
    ['P_Rvr'    ,'7'],
    ['P_ER SH NE',  '13'],
    ['P_ER SH M'    ,'3']]
    
PRK_sourceT_sum_df=pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['19-SOURCE','19-AMOUNT','19-SOURCE_PRK'])
Sourcedata_df=pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['PRK Source Code','Fid seq Num'])
    
for i in PRK_sourceT_sum_df['19-SOURCE']:
        
    
            for j,k in zip(Sourcedata_df['PRK Source Code'],Sourcedata_df['Fid seq Num']):
                if i !='0':            
                    if i.strip()== j.strip():
                    
                        l1=str(i)
                        l2=str(k)
                        print ('here is prk and fidelity source number')
                        print (l1,l2)
            PRK_sourceT_sum_df['19-SOURCE'] = [*map(lambda x: x.replace(l1,l2), PRK_sourceT_sum_df['19-SOURCE'])]
```

I am getting output like below:

```
19-SOURCE   19-AMOUNT   19-SOURCE_PRK
3               456     ER SH M
13              823     ER SH NE
7               346     Rvr
7 A-T           175     Rvr A-T
7 R             446     Rvr R
4               642     U ER Act
```

My desired result is as below:

```
19-SOURCE   19-AMOUNT   19-SOURCE_PRK
3               456     ER SH M
13              823     ER SH NE
7               346     Rvr
9               175     Rvr A-T
8               446     Rvr R
4               642     U ER Act
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Paste your actual output as [formatted text](/help/formatting) instead of an image. See my edit to your question for pointers on using code-blocks

Comment: thank you @PranavHosangadi. Now i see it is closed, does that mean no one will see/respond to my question

Comment: yes, nobody will be able to answer. You can put it in the reopen queue if you fix the problem(s) with your question that caused it to get closed in the first place. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Also: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953) and [mre]s in general. @ me once you've done so, and I'll give some feedback and vote to reopen if appropriate

Comment: thank you. i have tried to look for similar question but did not get a proper solution. Also i will update my question with some better statements. Please vote to reopen it.

Comment: You need to update it _before_ I vote to reopen.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi , i tried to include as much as i can. Please let me know if this looks good.